# Two circuits in same junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box, circuit

Can two different circuits go through the same junction box?  That is, two cables enter from different breakers and they tie to cables exiting, but the two circuits aren't connected except for the grounds if that is required.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is fine. The only restriction would be mixing voltage classes. You couldn’t mix line voltage and low voltage (e.g. 12 volts) in the same box.

You can interconnect the grounds or not. If the box is metal and the conduit is not (or no conduit), you’ll need to tie one or both grounds to the box.

Be careful not to mix or interconnect the neutrals or hots.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Thanks, fixed. I was typing on my iPad and somehow autocorrect did that. My bad or not noticing.

Comment: Pay attention to the box fill requirements. Overfill may be more likely with two or more neutral bundles.

Comment: Yes, everything will be 110V.  What if the box is metal and conduit or armored cable?...Still tie both grounds to box I assume?

Comment: NEC 250.148 ...If conductors are spliced....all equipment grounding conductor(s) shall be connected within the box or to the box...314.4 ...Metal boxes shall be grounded...